# Switch vs toggle

Tags: android-layout, switch-statement, toggle, uiswitch

I'm trying to decide whether to use a switch or toggle for setting an alarm I'm my android application. On fairly new to android and don't know or quite understand all the ins and outs of the frame work. What would be the disadvantages of choosing to trigger the alarm with a switch over a toggle, or vice versa? Is there a slide toggle available in android framework?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing you need to keep in mind is since which API do you want to compile your app?

[Toggle Buttons](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) are available since **API 1** and [Switches](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) are only available since **API 14**.

Besides that is just a simple decision, which one is the best option for user interface/design
In my opinion Switches give a clear indication of what is currently selected.

> Is there a slide toggle available in android framework?

Yes a switch can work as a slide toggle.

The code is very simple, you can basically use the same thought for these two buttons.

**Here is an example of a Switch Button**

```
btnSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_1);

btnSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            Log.i("Switch", "ON");
        } else {
            Log.i("Switch", "OFF");
        }
    }
});
```

**Here's an example of a toggle Button**

```
btnToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle_1);

btnToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            Log.i("Toggle", "ON");
        } else {
            Log.i("Toggle", "OFF");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank so much for your answer! This was very helpful. I just want to sure because in the  documentation there weren't any motivator differences in functionality from what i could see, i w wanted to know which one developers usually looked at as the better choice. From more research and your answer, i would have to say switchers seen to be the more popular choice.