# Change switch icon color from java code

Tags: java, android, android-togglebutton

I want to change the 'switch' icon color from java code and not from xml since the switch is created dynamically.
Min SDK is 16.
Help would be highly appreciated.

```
    Switch aSwitch = new Switch(context);
    holder.llSwitch.addView(aSwitch); 
    holder.navIcon.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.fa_bell_o));
```

Comment: Try to use: android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat

Comment: try .setTintColor

Comment: @RajeshKushvaha it did not work. Rather there is no such attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check button is checkd or not and set the color with the state

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
Switch mySwitch = new Switch(this);
linearLayout.addView(mySwitch);
mySwitch.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        if (isChecked)
            buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        else buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
});
```

---

Since you are messing up with `Switch` and `ToggleButton` check this answer [Switch vs toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776356/switch-vs-toggle#)

**Edit** : Only for thumb color change you can try like below

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
final Switch mySwitch = new Switch(this);
linearLayout.addView(mySwitch);
mySwitch.getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        if (isChecked)
            mySwitch.getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        else
            mySwitch.getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
});
```

Comment: But this is a toggle button and I need to use Switch.

Comment: `isChecked()` funtion is there too lazy to type again check this http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/04/android-switch-button-example.html

Comment: I want to change the toggle colour which is by default black (isChecked()) to red

Comment: @Aparajita Sinha  okay what stops you then, when you create it give it a color ->black , then once `setOnCheckedChangeListener` gets fired check the state using `isChecked` then you can use if else conditions your job is Done

Comment: That's right but I cannot find an attribute to set this. I cannot set a style from java for switch.

Comment: @Aparajita Sinha Did i set a style its just background color that i set `buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);` added a Link to help you with switch and toggle

Comment: **buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);** This sets an external background to the switch layout..

Comment: @Aparajita Sinha post your code of dynamic Switch  creation

Comment: @Aparajita Sinha  you want only to change the icon color?

Comment: @Aparajita Sinha updated ! you can mark it as correct answer now xoxo

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. My accepted answer is the edited answer